# Problems starting iOS driver

Tags: ios, emulation

I am having difficulty with executing a test with my driver.

1) I start my server with the following (grid does not start as I am getting kicked out… for another thread)

```
java -jar ios-server-standalone-0.6.6-SNAPSHOT.jar -port 1111
```

2) I launch a test from the respective directory

3) The logs dump the following:

```
The server cannot run Capabilities [{platform=MAC, cssSelectorsEnabled=false, CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.mobilesafari, javascriptEnabled=true, nativeEvents=false, locale=en_GB, CFBundleName=Safari, variation=Retina4, device=iphone, rotatable=false, takesScreenshot=false, sdkVersion=7.1, version=}] at the moment.org.uiautomation.ios.application.APPIOSApplication cannot be cast to org.uiautomation.ios.application.IPAApplication

Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

System info: host: '(hidden for privacy)', ip: '(hidden for privacy)', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.5', java.version: '1.7.0_67'

Driver info: driver.version: unknown

Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'

System info: host: '(hidden for privacy)', ip: '(hidden for privacy)', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.9.5', java.version: '1.7.0_67'

Driver info: driver.version: unknown (org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException) (Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError)

[remote server] org.uiautomation.ios.command.uiautomation.NewSessionNHandler(NewSessionNHandler.java):100:in `safeStart'
```

What is the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Having had the exact same issue, you could try using

```
capabilities.setCapability("simulator", true);
```

This got me past this issue at least (and into another one).

Comment: This isn't an answer it's a comment and should be added as one. To get the reputation to add comments you must provide good answers and questions to build your reputation. Please don't leave answers that are just saying I'm having the same problem that isn't how this works. Flagged for deletion.